# On exponential stability of fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am a bit lost in the concepts of stability theory. Consider the (non-linear) ODE $x' = \varphi(x)$ in some Banach space with a unique stationary point $x_*.$

Then we could say that the fixed point is (globally) exponentially stable if there exists an $\alpha > 0$ such that
$$ \|x_* - x(t)\| \leq e^{-\alpha t} \|x_* - x(0)\| $$ holds for any $t \geq 0$
and any initial $x(0).$ But we could also define the concept of stability through the solution curves. That is, the system is exponentially stable if there is an $\alpha > 0$ such that
$$ \|x_1(t) - x_2(t)\| \leq e^{-\alpha t} \|x_1(0) - x_2(0)\| $$ holds for any $t \geq 0$ and $x(0), y(0).$

The second definition readily implies the first property of $x_*.$ But I do not see any simple proof of the converse statement and do not have any counterexample either. Still, I naively think that these two stabilities are the same. Please, could you give any reference to these types of results?

Answer (score 1):

The requirement for exponential stability is a little less strict as your first inequality. Namely, one can also [include a constant positive but finite factor $\beta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Definition_for_continuous-time_systems), such that initial transients are allowed

$$
\|x_* - x(t)\| \leq \beta\,e^{-\alpha t} \|x_* - x(0)\|\quad \forall\ t \geq 0.
$$

For your proposed second definition I initially though that it would still allow for [limit cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle). However, there is no driving force, which causes the two solutions to synchronize. One other possibility is that the system is unstable and the state goes to infinity but at a slower and slower rate. I have tried to come up with an example of this, but have not been able to proof that neighboring solutions of the system below exponentially converge

$$
\dot{x} = x\,e^{-x^4},
$$

but numerically simulations do seem to agree with this.

---

For nonautonomous systems one can come up with counter examples, where there are bounded state trajectories that have a basin of attraction, such as

\begin{align}
r(t) &= 2 + \sin(\omega\,t), \\
w(t,x) &= (1 + 10^8\,(r(t) - x)^8)^{-1}, \\
\dot{x} &= (w(t,x) - 1)\,x + w(t,x) \left(k\,(r(t) - x) + \dot{r}(t)\right).
\end{align}

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your reasoning. According to the first property, the system is globally stable. How can you disprove the second property via an unstable construction or limit cycles?

Comment: @zoli I might be misinterpreting your question. Namely, I read it as if there is some set, such that for all $x_1(0)$ and $x_2(0)$ in that set it holds that your second condition holds, that you wondered if the first condition would then also hold. But this is only the case if $x^*$ is also part of that set.